# PromTail JSON Scrape Special Character

Tags: json, jmespath, promtail

For a PromTail scrape config, I am using a JSON stage.

I have a JSON log that looks like this:

```json
{
   "@l": "info",
   "foo": "bar"
}
```

I am looking to use the JSON stage to extract the `@l` property into the map.

I tried this:

```
- json:
     expressions:
       level: '"@l"'
- labels:
     level:
```

The agent starts but no logs are scraped. If I remove the JSON stage, tons of logs come in.

What could I be doing wrong with the `@` escape sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed. To escape a `@` or `.`, you use double quotes.

so examples:

```
{
   "@l": "Debug",
   "foo.bar": "value"
}
```

`'"@l"'`

or

`'"foo.bar"'`

[Source](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/json/#using-a-jmespath-literal)

**Using a JMESPath Literal**

This pipeline uses a literal JMESPath expression to parse JSON fields with special characters in the name, like @ or .